# How to get the row value from ng-grid in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How can I get a row value, when click cell in `ng-grid`?

example:

```
Name   Number  Class

X      123      A

Y      234      B

Z      345      C

A      456      D
```

When click on 123 cell or A cell or X cell, how can i get value X.

Please any help me. thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `ng-click` of cellTemplate `ng-click="clicked(row)"`

**Controller**

```
$scope.clicked = function(row){
   alert(row.getProperty("Name"));
};
```

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar, when i click any cell, i want corresponding name value. how can i get the value

Comment: @stackoverflow you need to add `ng-click` in cellTemplate of colunn

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar, i have ng-clcik in cellTemplate only, but hiw can i get name values when click on number cell or class Cell, can please help me it

Comment: you ng-click of cell template should be `ng-click="clicked(row, col)"`, did you tried the changes which i suggested

Answer (score 0):

One option - add an `ng-click` function on each row that returns the value in the first column.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getVal(item)">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.number}}</td>
  <td>{{item.class}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getVal = function(item) {
    alert(item.name);
}
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/u9ymkdq6/).